# Parametric solutions for the quadratic Diophantine equation $2a^2 + b^2 = 2c^2 + d^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

I'm new to this area of number theory and have a limited understanding and intuition for how to find parametric solutions for Diophantine equations with degrees $>1$. Today, I'm specifically interested in $2a^2 + b^2 = 2c^2 + d^2$.

I would like to learn about the methods one would refer to to:

a) Find out how many solutions exist

b) If the answer to a) is more than 1, then I would also like to know how many parametric forms would exist i.e. such that the $GCD(a,b,c,d)=1$

c) Derive the parameterized forms if they exist.

Comment: $b^2-2c^2=d^2-2a^2=1$ is [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and has infinitely many solutions:  $(b,c),(d,a)\in\{(1,0),(3,2),(17,12),(99,70)\dots\}$

Comment: Excellent! That pretty much solves a)

Comment: Could we generalize the rest as a scaled Pell's equation? Something like $k(b^2 - 2c^2) = k(d^2 - 2a^2) = k$?

Comment: Would that still allow us to apply our understanding of the Pell's Equation to write down more general parameters?

Comment: you could read [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) about a more complicated Pell-like equation $x^2-2y^2=k$ [Mathworld page, equation (39)]

Comment: I would approach this by applying [Hilbert 90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90) to the field extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})/\Bbb{Q}$. After all, the equation also says that the norm of $w=(b+a\sqrt{-2})/(d+c\sqrt{-2})$ is equal to one. So we know that $w=\overline{z}/z$ for some $z\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$. It should be possible to turn that into a parametrization of the full set of solutions. But it's past midnight here and I can't think straight. Probably some issues with non-uniqueness of the fraction (even though the class number is $h=1$).

Comment: Äh, probably easier to use the norm of the UFD $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. A rational prime $p$ splits there iff $p\equiv1,3\pmod8$, and we can use the resulting conjugate pairs as factors of $b+a\sqrt{-2}$ and $d+c\sqrt{-2}$ respectively.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  got it, answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with taking $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|$ in the recipes below. You still get the desired relationship.

$$  a = 2 pq + qs + pr  $$
$$ b = 2 pq -rs - 2 qs $$
$$ c = 2pq - qs + pr  $$
$$ d = 2pq +rs + 2 qs $$

```
?   a = 2 * p*q + q*s + p*r;  b = 2 *p*q -r*s - 2* q*s ;    c = 2*p*q - q*s + p*r ;   d = 2*p*q +r*s + 2* q*s;

? 
? 2 * a^2 + b^2
%2 = (12*q^2 + 8*r*q + 2*r^2)*p^2 + (6*s^2*q^2 + 4*r*s^2*q + r^2*s^2)
? 2 * c^2 + d^2
%3 = (12*q^2 + 8*r*q + 2*r^2)*p^2 + (6*s^2*q^2 + 4*r*s^2*q + r^2*s^2)

? 2 * a^2 + b^2 -  2 * c^2 - d^2
%5 = 0
?
```

==============================================

Slightly less repetition after I demanded $|a| > |c|.$ So, for example, this does not show abcd = (1,0,1,0) or (0,1,0,1)

```
  a      b      c      d           p      q      r      s
  2      1      0      3           1      1     -1      1
  2      1      0      3           1     -1      1      1
  2      1      0      3           1      1     -3     -1
  2      1      0      3           1     -1      3     -1
  3      0      1      4           1      1      0      1
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      0      1
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -1      2
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      1      2
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -3     -2
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      3     -2
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -4     -1
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      4     -1
  3      3      1      5           1      2     -3      1
  3      3      1      5           1     -2      3      1
  3      3      1      5           1      2     -5     -1
  3      3      1      5           1     -2      5     -1
  3      3      1      5           2      1     -1      1
  3      3      1      5           2     -1      1      1
  3      3      1      5           2      1     -3     -1
  3      3      1      5           2     -1      3     -1
  4      1      2      5           1      1      1      1
  4      1      2      5           1     -1     -1      1
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -1      3
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      1      3
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -3     -3
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      3     -3
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -5     -1
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      5     -1
  4      5      2      7           1      3     -5      1
  4      5      2      7           1     -3      5      1
  4      5      2      7           3      1     -1      1
  4      5      2      7           3     -1      1      1
  4      5      2      7           3      1     -3     -1
  4      5      2      7           3     -1      3     -1
  4      7      0      9           2      2     -3      1
  4      7      0      9           2     -2      3      1
  4      7      0      9           2      2     -5     -1
  4      7      0      9           2     -2      5     -1
  5     11      1     13           2      3     -5      1
  5     11      1     13           2     -3      5      1
  5     11      1     13           3      2     -3      1
  5     11      1     13           3     -2      3      1
  5     11      1     13           3      2     -5     -1
  5     11      1     13           3     -2      5     -1
  5      1      1      7           1      2     -1      1
  5      1      1      7           1     -2      1      1
  5      1      1      7           2      1     -1      3
  5      1      1      7           2     -1      1      3
  5      1      1      7           2      1     -3     -3
  5      1      1      7           2     -1      3     -3
  5      2      3      6           1      1     -1      4
  5      2      3      6           1     -1      1      4
  5      2      3      6           1      1      2      1
  5      2      3      6           1     -1     -2      1
  5      2      3      6           1      1     -3     -4
  5      2      3      6           1     -1      3     -4
  5      2      3      6           1      2     -3      2
  5      2      3      6           1     -2      3      2
  5      2      3      6           1      2     -5     -2
  5      2      3      6           1     -2      5     -2
  5      2      3      6           2      1      0      1
  5      2      3      6           2     -1      0      1
  5      2      3      6           2      1     -4     -1
  5      2      3      6           2     -1      4     -1
  5      4      1      8           1      1      0      3
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      0      3
  5      4      1      8           1      1      1      2
  5      4      1      8           1     -1     -1      2
  5      4      1      8           1      1     -4     -3
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      4     -3
  5      4      1      8           1      1     -5     -2
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      5     -2
  5      4      1      8           1      3     -4      1
  5      4      1      8           1     -3      4      1
  5      4      1      8           3      1     -1      2
  5      4      1      8           3     -1      1      2
  5      4      1      8           3      1     -3     -2
  5      4      1      8           3     -1      3     -2
  5      7      3      9           4      1     -1      1
  5      7      3      9           4     -1      1      1
  5      7      3      9           4      1     -3     -1
  5      7      3      9           4     -1      3     -1
  6     15      2     17           4      2     -3      1
  6     15      2     17           4     -2      3      1
  6     15      2     17           4      2     -5     -1
  6     15      2     17           4     -2      5     -1
  6     17      0     19           3      3     -5      1
  6     17      0     19           3     -3      5      1
  6      3      4      7           1      1     -1      5
  6      3      4      7           1     -1      1      5
  6      3      4      7           1      1      3      1
  6      3      4      7           1     -1     -3      1
  6      3      4      7           1      1     -3     -5
  6      3      4      7           1     -1      3     -5
  6      7      0     11           1      1      1      3
  6      7      0     11           1     -1     -1      3
  6      7      0     11           1      1     -5     -3
  6      7      0     11           1     -1      5     -3
  6      9      4     11           5      1     -1      1
  6      9      4     11           5     -1      1      1
  6      9      4     11           5      1     -3     -1
  6      9      4     11           5     -1      3     -1
  7     10      1     14           1      1      1      4
  7     10      1     14           1     -1     -1      4
  7     10      1     14           1      1      2      3
  7     10      1     14           1     -1     -2      3
  7     10      1     14           1      1     -5     -4
  7     10      1     14           1     -1      5     -4
  7     10      1     14           2      3     -4      1
  7     10      1     14           2     -3      4      1
  7     10      1     14           3      2     -3      2
  7     10      1     14           3     -2      3      2
  7     10      1     14           3      2     -5     -2
  7     10      1     14           3     -2      5     -2
  7      1      3      9           1      2      1      1
  7      1      3      9           1     -2     -1      1
  7      1      3      9           2      1     -1      5
  7      1      3      9           2     -1      1      5
  7      1      3      9           2      1     -3     -5
  7      1      3      9           2     -1      3     -5
  7      1      5      7           1      2     -3      3
  7      1      5      7           1     -2      3      3
  7      1      5      7           1      2     -5     -3
  7      1      5      7           1     -2      5     -3
  7      1      5      7           2      1      1      1
  7      1      5      7           2     -1     -1      1
  7      1      5      7           2      1     -5     -1
  7      1      5      7           2     -1      5     -1
  7     19      3     21           5      2     -3      1
  7     19      3     21           5     -2      3      1
  7     19      3     21           5      2     -5     -1
  7     19      3     21           5     -2      5     -1
  7      2      1     10           1      2     -1      2
  7      2      1     10           1     -2      1      2
  7      2      1     10           1      3     -2      1
  7      2      1     10           1     -3      2      1
  7      2      1     10           2      1      0      3
  7      2      1     10           2     -1      0      3
  7      2      1     10           2      1     -4     -3
  7      2      1     10           2     -1      4     -3
  7      2      1     10           3      1     -1      4
  7      2      1     10           3     -1      1      4
  7      2      1     10           3      1     -3     -4
  7      2      1     10           3     -1      3     -4
  7     23      1     25           4      3     -5      1
  7     23      1     25           4     -3      5      1
  7      4      5      8           1      1      4      1
  7      4      5      8           1     -1     -4      1
  7      4      5      8           1      3     -5      2
  7      4      5      8           1     -3      5      2
  7      4      5      8           3      1      0      1
  7      4      5      8           3     -1      0      1
  7      4      5      8           3      1     -4     -1
  7      4      5      8           3     -1      4     -1
  7      5      1     11           1      4     -5      1
  7      5      1     11           1     -4      5      1
  7      5      1     11           4      1     -1      3
  7      5      1     11           4     -1      1      3
  7      5      1     11           4      1     -3     -3
  7      5      1     11           4     -1      3     -3
  7      8      3     12           1      1      0      5
  7      8      3     12           1     -1      0      5
  7      8      3     12           1      1      3      2
  7      8      3     12           1     -1     -3      2
  7      8      3     12           1      1     -4     -5
  7      8      3     12           1     -1      4     -5
  7      8      3     12           5      1     -1      2
  7      8      3     12           5     -1      1      2
  7      8      3     12           5      1     -3     -2
  7      8      3     12           5     -1      3     -2
  8      1      2     11           1      3     -1      1
  8      1      2     11           1     -3      1      1
  8      1      2     11           3      1     -1      5
  8      1      2     11           3     -1      1      5
  8      1      2     11           3      1     -3     -5
  8      1      2     11           3     -1      3     -5
  8     13      2     17           1      1      1      5
  8     13      2     17           1     -1     -1      5
  8     13      2     17           1      1      3      3
  8     13      2     17           1     -1     -3      3
  8     13      2     17           1      1     -5     -5
  8     13      2     17           1     -1      5     -5
  8     29      2     31           5      3     -5      1
  8     29      2     31           5     -3      5      1
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -1      1
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      1      1
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -3      3
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      3      3
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -5     -3
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      5     -3
  8      5      6      9           1      1      5      1
  8      5      6      9           1     -1     -5      1
  8      7      2     13           5      1     -1      3
  8      7      2     13           5     -1      1      3
  8      7      2     13           5      1     -3     -3
  8      7      2     13           5     -1      3     -3
  9      0      7      8           1      2     -3      4
  9      0      7      8           1     -2      3      4
  9      0      7      8           1      2     -5     -4
  9      0      7      8           1     -2      5     -4
  9      0      7      8           2      1      2      1
  9      0      7      8           2     -1     -2      1
  9     12      5     16           1      1      5      2
  9     12      5     16           1     -1     -5      2
  9     16      3     20           1      1      4      3
  9     16      3     20           1     -1     -4      3
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -4      1
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      4      1
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -5      2
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      5      2
  9     18      1     22           1      1      2      5
  9     18      1     22           1     -1     -2      5
  9     18      1     22           1      1      3      4
  9     18      1     22           1     -1     -3      4
  9     18      1     22           5      2     -3      2
  9     18      1     22           5     -2      3      2
  9     18      1     22           5      2     -5     -2
  9     18      1     22           5     -2      5     -2
  9      3      1     13           1      4     -3      1
  9      3      1     13           1     -4      3      1
  9      3      1     13           4      1     -1      5
  9      3      1     13           4     -1      1      5
  9      3      1     13           4      1     -3     -5
  9      3      1     13           4     -1      3     -5
  9      3      5     11           1      2      3      1
  9      3      5     11           1     -2     -3      1
  9      5      3     13           1      2     -1      3
  9      5      3     13           1     -2      1      3
  9      5      3     13           2      1      1      3
  9      5      3     13           2     -1     -1      3
  9      5      3     13           2      1     -5     -3
  9      5      3     13           2     -1      5     -3
  9      6      1     14           1      2      1      2
  9      6      1     14           1     -2     -1      2
  9      6      1     14           2      1      0      5
  9      6      1     14           2     -1      0      5
  9      6      1     14           2      1     -4     -5
  9      6      1     14           2     -1      4     -5
  9      6      1     14           5      1     -1      4
  9      6      1     14           5     -1      1      4
  9      6      1     14           5      1     -3     -4
  9      6      1     14           5     -1      3     -4
  9      6      7     10           4      1      0      1
  9      6      7     10           4     -1      0      1
  9      6      7     10           4      1     -4     -1
  9      6      7     10           4     -1      4     -1
 10     13      2     19           2      4     -5      1
 10     13      2     19           2     -4      5      1
 10     13      2     19           4      2     -3      3
 10     13      2     19           4     -2      3      3
 10     13      2     19           4      2     -5     -3
 10     13      2     19           4     -2      5     -3
 10      1      4     13           1      3      1      1
 10      1      4     13           1     -3     -1      1
 10     19      4     23           1      1      5      3
 10     19      4     23           1     -1     -5      3
 10     23      0     27           1      1      3      5
 10     23      0     27           1     -1     -3      5
 10      3      8      9           1      3     -5      3
 10      3      8      9           1     -3      5      3
 10      3      8      9           3      1      1      1
 10      3      8      9           3     -1     -1      1
 10      3      8      9           3      1     -5     -1
 10      3      8      9           3     -1      5     -1
 11      0      7     12           1      3     -4      3
 11      0      7     12           1     -3      4      3
 11      0      7     12           3      1      1      2
 11      0      7     12           3     -1     -1      2
 11      0      7     12           3      1     -5     -2
 11      0      7     12           3     -1      5     -2
 11     10      3     18           1      2      3      2
 11     10      3     18           1     -2     -3      2
 11     11      1     19           1      2      1      3
 11     11      1     19           1     -2     -1      3
 11     11      1     19           2      1      1      5
 11     11      1     19           2     -1     -1      5
 11     11      1     19           2      1     -5     -5
 11     11      1     19           2     -1      5     -5
 11      1      3     15           1      4     -1      1
 11      1      3     15           1     -4      1      1
 11     17      1     23           5      2     -3      3
 11     17      1     23           5     -2      3      3
 11     17      1     23           5      2     -5     -3
 11     17      1     23           5     -2      5     -3
 11      1      9      9           1      2     -3      5
 11      1      9      9           1     -2      3      5
 11      1      9      9           1      2     -5     -5
 11      1      9      9           1     -2      5     -5
 11      1      9      9           2      1      3      1
 11      1      9      9           2     -1     -3      1
 11     22      5     26           4      3     -4      1
 11     22      5     26           4     -3      4      1
 11      2      5     14           1      3      2      1
 11      2      5     14           1     -3     -2      1
 11      2      5     14           1      4     -5      2
 11      2      5     14           1     -4      5      2
 11      2      5     14           4      1      0      3
 11      2      5     14           4     -1      0      3
 11      2      5     14           4      1     -4     -3
 11      2      5     14           4     -1      4     -3
 11     26      3     30           1      1      5      4
 11     26      3     30           1     -1     -5      4
 11     28      1     32           1      1      4      5
 11     28      1     32           1     -1     -4      5
 11     28      1     32           5      3     -5      2
 11     28      1     32           5     -3      5      2
 11      4      1     16           1      3     -1      2
 11      4      1     16           1     -3      1      2
 11      4      1     16           1      5     -4      1
 11      4      1     16           1     -5      4      1
 11      4      1     16           3      1      0      5
 11      4      1     16           3     -1      0      5
 11      4      1     16           3      1     -4     -5
 11      4      1     16           3     -1      4     -5
 11      5      7     13           1      2      5      1
 11      5      7     13           1     -2     -5      1
 11      8      5     16           1      2     -1      4
 11      8      5     16           1     -2      1      4
 11      8      5     16           2      1      2      3
 11      8      5     16           2     -1     -2      3
 11      8      5     16           2      3     -2      1
 11      8      5     16           2     -3      2      1
 11      8      5     16           3      2     -3      4
 11      8      5     16           3     -2      3      4
 11      8      5     16           3      2     -5     -4
 11      8      5     16           3     -2      5     -4
 11      8      9     12           5      1      0      1
 11      8      9     12           5     -1      0      1
 11      8      9     12           5      1     -4     -1
 11      8      9     12           5     -1      4     -1
 11      9      7     15           2      3     -5      3
 11      9      7     15           2     -3      5      3
 11      9      7     15           3      2     -1      1
 11      9      7     15           3     -2      1      1
 12      1      0     17           2      2     -1      3
 12      1      0     17           2     -2      1      3
 12      3      2     17           1      5     -3      1
 12      3      2     17           1     -5      3      1
 12     33      2     37           1      1      5      5
 12     33      2     37           1     -1     -5      5
 12      3      8     13           2      2      1      1
 12      3      8     13           2     -2     -1      1
 12      3      8     13           2      2     -3      5
 12      3      8     13           2     -2      3      5
 12      3      8     13           2      2     -5     -5
 12      3      8     13           2     -2      5     -5
 13     11      7     19           1      2     -1      5
 13     11      7     19           1     -2      1      5
 13     11      7     19           2      1      3      3
 13     11      7     19           2     -1     -3      3
 13     14      5     22           1      2      5      2
 13     14      5     22           1     -2     -5      2
 13      1      5     17           1      4      1      1
 13      1      5     17           1     -4     -1      1
 13     16      3     24           1      2      1      4
 13     16      3     24           1     -2     -1      4
 13     16      3     24           2      1      2      5
 13     16      3     24           2     -1     -2      5
 13     16      3     24           5      2     -3      4
 13     16      3     24           5     -2      3      4
 13     16      3     24           5      2     -5     -4
 13     16      3     24           5     -2      5     -4
 13     17      1     25           1      2      3      3
 13     17      1     25           1     -2     -3      3
 13      2     11     10           1      3     -5      4
 13      2     11     10           1     -3      5      4
 13      2     11     10           2      1      4      1
 13      2     11     10           2     -1     -4      1
 13      2     11     10           3      1      2      1
 13      2     11     10           3     -1     -2      1
 13     21      5     27           3      4     -5      1
 13     21      5     27           3     -4      5      1
 13     21      5     27           4      3     -5      3
 13     21      5     27           4     -3      5      3
 13      2      3     18           1      4     -3      2
 13      2      3     18           1     -4      3      2
 13      2      3     18           1      5     -2      1
 13      2      3     18           1     -5      2      1
 13      2      3     18           4      1      0      5
 13      2      3     18           4     -1      0      5
 13      2      3     18           4      1     -4     -5
 13      2      3     18           4     -1      4     -5
 13     28      7     32           5      3     -4      1
 13     28      7     32           5     -3      4      1
 13      4      7     16           1      3      4      1
 13      4      7     16           1     -3     -4      1
 13      4      7     16           5      1      0      3
 13      4      7     16           5     -1      0      3
 13      4      7     16           5      1     -4     -3
 13      4      7     16           5     -1      4     -3
 13      5     11     11           4      1      1      1
 13      5     11     11           4     -1     -1      1
 13      5     11     11           4      1     -5     -1
 13      5     11     11           4     -1      5     -1
 13      6      5     18           1      3     -2      3
 13      6      5     18           1     -3      2      3
 13      6      5     18           2      3     -4      3
 13      6      5     18           2     -3      4      3
 13      6      5     18           3      1      1      4
 13      6      5     18           3     -1     -1      4
 13      6      5     18           3      1     -5     -4
 13      6      5     18           3     -1      5     -4
 13      6      5     18           3      2     -1      2
 13      6      5     18           3     -2      1      2
 13      7      7     17           2      3     -1      1
 13      7      7     17           2     -3      1      1
 13      7      7     17           3      2     -3      5
 13      7      7     17           3     -2      3      5
 13      7      7     17           3      2     -5     -5
 13      7      7     17           3     -2      5     -5
 13      8      1     20           1      3      1      2
 13      8      1     20           1     -3     -1      2
 14     11      6     21           2      4     -3      1
 14     11      6     21           2     -4      3      1
 14     11      6     21           4      2     -3      5
 14     11      6     21           4     -2      3      5
 14     11      6     21           4      2     -5     -5
 14     11      6     21           4     -2      5     -5
 14     13     10     19           4      2     -1      1
 14     13     10     19           4     -2      1      1
 14      1      4     19           1      5     -1      1
 14      1      4     19           1     -5      1      1
 14     27      4     33           5      3     -5      3
 14     27      4     33           5     -3      5      3
 14      5      8     17           1      3      5      1
 14      5      8     17           1     -3     -5      1
 14      9      4     21           1      3     -1      3
 14      9      4     21           1     -3      1      3
 14      9      4     21           3      1      1      5
 14      9      4     21           3     -1     -1      5
 14      9      4     21           3      1     -5     -5
 14      9      4     21           3     -1      5     -5
 15     14      9     22           2      1      4      3
 15     14      9     22           2     -1     -4      3
 15     14      9     22           3      3     -2      1
 15     14      9     22           3     -3      2      1
 15     14      9     22           3      3     -5      4
 15     14      9     22           3     -3      5      4
 15      1      9     17           1      4     -5      3
 15      1      9     17           1     -4      5      3
 15      1      9     17           4      1      1      3
 15      1      9     17           4     -1     -1      3
 15      1      9     17           4      1     -5     -3
 15      1      9     17           4     -1      5     -3
 15     21      5     29           1      2      1      5
 15     21      5     29           1     -2     -1      5
 15     21      5     29           2      1      3      5
 15     21      5     29           2     -1     -3      5
 15     23      3     31           1      2      5      3
 15     23      3     31           1     -2     -5      3
  a      b      c      d           p      q      r      s
```

============================================

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Does this form account for all of the solutions? How would we show that?

Comment: @antoniomathgini  I used a method suggested by Fricke and Klein (1897). I suspect that a proof based on insisting $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$ would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Write the equation as
$$ 2 (a^2 - c^2) = d^2 - b^2$$
i.e.
$$ 2 (a+c)(a-c) = (d+b)(d-b) $$
Now $d+b$ and $d-b$ must be both even (they must have the same parity since $d = ((d+b)+(d-b))/2$ is an integer, and they can't be both odd because $2 (a+c)(a-c)$ is even.  Then
$(a+c)(a-c)$ is even, so $a+c$ and $a-c$ are both even.  We can write $a+c = 2 x y$, $a-c = 2 z w$, $d+b = 4 x z$, $d-b = 2  y w$, so $a = xy + zw$, $c = xy - zw$, $d = 2 x z + y w$, 
$b = 2 x z - y w$, or else $d+b = 2 y w$ and $d-b = 4 x z$, which produces a solution that is the same except for $b = -2xz + yw$.

Comment: Thanks! So would this generate entirely distinct solutions from the form in the other answers? Even if there is some overlap, I wonder how many such forms it would take to describe all of the solutions to the equation...

Comment: @antoniomathgini both recipes give all solutions. Just one is needed.

Comment: @WillJagy Then what is meant by Brute Force in your second answer? My understanding was that BRUTE FORCE describes solutions that are not described by the parameterized formula

Comment: I think I understand now. Correct me if I'm wrong. You used a brute force search to compare the results with the parameterized formula to make sure that no solutions were being missed. Hence there are (a,b,c,d) parameter-formula solutions right before their BRUTE FORCE equivalent. The first example of this is (2,1,0,3). Fair?

Comment: @antoniomathgini yes. The Fricke-Klein thing did give a version of Robert's answer, as      -8  minus signs  2 zero count:   8
      1      1      0      0
      0      0      2      1
      1     -1      0      0
      0      0      2     -1
in order a,d,b,c.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it most effective to combine a brute force list with the list produced by the parametrization, then sort as one list. If any line that says BRUTE FORCE is not covered, that sticks out.

$$  a = 2 pq + qs + pr \; , \; \; 
 b = 2 pq -rs - 2 qs \; , \; \;
 c = 2pq - qs + pr  \; , \; \;
 d = 2pq +rs + 2 qs $$

=======================================================================

```
  a      b      c      d           p      q      r      s 
  2      1      0      3           1      1     -1      1
  2      1      0      3           1     -1      1      1
  2      1      0      3           1      1     -3     -1
  2      1      0      3           1     -1      3     -1
  2      1      0      3  BRUTE FORCE       
  3      0      1      4           1      1      0      1
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      0      1
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -1      2
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      1      2
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -3     -2
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      3     -2
  3      0      1      4           1      1     -4     -1
  3      0      1      4           1     -1      4     -1
  3      0      1      4  BRUTE FORCE       
  3      3      1      5           1      2     -3      1
  3      3      1      5           1     -2      3      1
  3      3      1      5           1      2     -5     -1
  3      3      1      5           1     -2      5     -1
  3      3      1      5           2      1     -1      1
  3      3      1      5           2     -1      1      1
  3      3      1      5           2      1     -3     -1
  3      3      1      5           2     -1      3     -1
  3      3      1      5  BRUTE FORCE       
  4      1      2      5           1      1      1      1
  4      1      2      5           1     -1     -1      1
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -1      3
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      1      3
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -3     -3
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      3     -3
  4      1      2      5           1      1     -5     -1
  4      1      2      5           1     -1      5     -1
  4      1      2      5  BRUTE FORCE       
  4      5      2      7           1      3     -5      1
  4      5      2      7           1     -3      5      1
  4      5      2      7           1      3     -7     -1
  4      5      2      7           1     -3      7     -1
  4      5      2      7           3      1     -1      1
  4      5      2      7           3     -1      1      1
  4      5      2      7           3      1     -3     -1
  4      5      2      7           3     -1      3     -1
  4      5      2      7  BRUTE FORCE       
  4      7      0      9           2      2     -3      1
  4      7      0      9           2     -2      3      1
  4      7      0      9           2      2     -5     -1
  4      7      0      9           2     -2      5     -1
  4      7      0      9  BRUTE FORCE       
  5     11      1     13           2      3     -5      1
  5     11      1     13           2     -3      5      1
  5     11      1     13           2      3     -7     -1
  5     11      1     13           2     -3      7     -1
  5     11      1     13           3      2     -3      1
  5     11      1     13           3     -2      3      1
  5     11      1     13           3      2     -5     -1
  5     11      1     13           3     -2      5     -1
  5     11      1     13  BRUTE FORCE       
  5      1      1      7           1      2     -1      1
  5      1      1      7           1     -2      1      1
  5      1      1      7           1      2     -7     -1
  5      1      1      7           1     -2      7     -1
  5      1      1      7           2      1     -1      3
  5      1      1      7           2     -1      1      3
  5      1      1      7           2      1     -3     -3
  5      1      1      7           2     -1      3     -3
  5      1      1      7  BRUTE FORCE       
  5      2      3      6           1      1     -1      4
  5      2      3      6           1     -1      1      4
  5      2      3      6           1      1      2      1
  5      2      3      6           1     -1     -2      1
  5      2      3      6           1      1     -3     -4
  5      2      3      6           1     -1      3     -4
  5      2      3      6           1      1     -6     -1
  5      2      3      6           1     -1      6     -1
  5      2      3      6           1      2     -3      2
  5      2      3      6           1     -2      3      2
  5      2      3      6           1      2     -5     -2
  5      2      3      6           1     -2      5     -2
  5      2      3      6           2      1      0      1
  5      2      3      6           2     -1      0      1
  5      2      3      6           2      1     -4     -1
  5      2      3      6           2     -1      4     -1
  5      2      3      6  BRUTE FORCE       
  5      4      1      8           1      1      0      3
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      0      3
  5      4      1      8           1      1      1      2
  5      4      1      8           1     -1     -1      2
  5      4      1      8           1      1     -4     -3
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      4     -3
  5      4      1      8           1      1     -5     -2
  5      4      1      8           1     -1      5     -2
  5      4      1      8           1      3     -4      1
  5      4      1      8           1     -3      4      1
  5      4      1      8           1      3     -8     -1
  5      4      1      8           1     -3      8     -1
  5      4      1      8           3      1     -1      2
  5      4      1      8           3     -1      1      2
  5      4      1      8           3      1     -3     -2
  5      4      1      8           3     -1      3     -2
  5      4      1      8  BRUTE FORCE       
  5      7      3      9           1      4     -7      1
  5      7      3      9           1     -4      7      1
  5      7      3      9           1      4     -9     -1
  5      7      3      9           1     -4      9     -1
  5      7      3      9           4      1     -1      1
  5      7      3      9           4     -1      1      1
  5      7      3      9           4      1     -3     -1
  5      7      3      9           4     -1      3     -1
  5      7      3      9  BRUTE FORCE       
  6     15      2     17           2      4     -7      1
  6     15      2     17           2     -4      7      1
  6     15      2     17           2      4     -9     -1
  6     15      2     17           2     -4      9     -1
  6     15      2     17           4      2     -3      1
  6     15      2     17           4     -2      3      1
  6     15      2     17           4      2     -5     -1
  6     15      2     17           4     -2      5     -1
  6     15      2     17  BRUTE FORCE       
  6     17      0     19           3      3     -5      1
  6     17      0     19           3     -3      5      1
  6     17      0     19           3      3     -7     -1
  6     17      0     19           3     -3      7     -1
  6     17      0     19  BRUTE FORCE       
  6      3      4      7           1      1     -1      5
  6      3      4      7           1     -1      1      5
  6      3      4      7           1      1      3      1
  6      3      4      7           1     -1     -3      1
  6      3      4      7           1      1     -3     -5
  6      3      4      7           1     -1      3     -5
  6      3      4      7           1      1     -7     -1
  6      3      4      7           1     -1      7     -1
  6      3      4      7  BRUTE FORCE       
  6      7      0     11           1      1      1      3
  6      7      0     11           1     -1     -1      3
  6      7      0     11           1      1     -5     -3
  6      7      0     11           1     -1      5     -3
  6      7      0     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  6      9      4     11           1      5     -9      1
  6      9      4     11           1     -5      9      1
  6      9      4     11           5      1     -1      1
  6      9      4     11           5     -1      1      1
  6      9      4     11           5      1     -3     -1
  6      9      4     11           5     -1      3     -1
  6      9      4     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  7     10      1     14           1      1      1      4
  7     10      1     14           1     -1     -1      4
  7     10      1     14           1      1      2      3
  7     10      1     14           1     -1     -2      3
  7     10      1     14           1      1     -5     -4
  7     10      1     14           1     -1      5     -4
  7     10      1     14           1      1     -6     -3
  7     10      1     14           1     -1      6     -3
  7     10      1     14           2      3     -4      1
  7     10      1     14           2     -3      4      1
  7     10      1     14           2      3     -8     -1
  7     10      1     14           2     -3      8     -1
  7     10      1     14           3      2     -3      2
  7     10      1     14           3     -2      3      2
  7     10      1     14           3      2     -5     -2
  7     10      1     14           3     -2      5     -2
  7     10      1     14  BRUTE FORCE       
  7     11      5     13           6      1     -1      1
  7     11      5     13           6     -1      1      1
  7     11      5     13           6      1     -3     -1
  7     11      5     13           6     -1      3     -1
  7     11      5     13  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      1      3      9           1      2      1      1
  7      1      3      9           1     -2     -1      1
  7      1      3      9           1      2     -9     -1
  7      1      3      9           1     -2      9     -1
  7      1      3      9           2      1     -1      5
  7      1      3      9           2     -1      1      5
  7      1      3      9           2      1     -3     -5
  7      1      3      9           2     -1      3     -5
  7      1      3      9  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      1      5      7           1      2     -3      3
  7      1      5      7           1     -2      3      3
  7      1      5      7           1      2     -5     -3
  7      1      5      7           1     -2      5     -3
  7      1      5      7           2      1      1      1
  7      1      5      7           2     -1     -1      1
  7      1      5      7           2      1     -5     -1
  7      1      5      7           2     -1      5     -1
  7      1      5      7  BRUTE FORCE       
  7     19      3     21           2      5     -9      1
  7     19      3     21           2     -5      9      1
  7     19      3     21           5      2     -3      1
  7     19      3     21           5     -2      3      1
  7     19      3     21           5      2     -5     -1
  7     19      3     21           5     -2      5     -1
  7     19      3     21  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      2      1     10           1      2     -1      2
  7      2      1     10           1     -2      1      2
  7      2      1     10           1      2     -7     -2
  7      2      1     10           1     -2      7     -2
  7      2      1     10           1      3    -10     -1
  7      2      1     10           1     -3     10     -1
  7      2      1     10           1      3     -2      1
  7      2      1     10           1     -3      2      1
  7      2      1     10           2      1      0      3
  7      2      1     10           2     -1      0      3
  7      2      1     10           2      1     -4     -3
  7      2      1     10           2     -1      4     -3
  7      2      1     10           3      1     -1      4
  7      2      1     10           3     -1      1      4
  7      2      1     10           3      1     -3     -4
  7      2      1     10           3     -1      3     -4
  7      2      1     10  BRUTE FORCE       
  7     23      1     25           3      4     -7      1
  7     23      1     25           3     -4      7      1
  7     23      1     25           3      4     -9     -1
  7     23      1     25           3     -4      9     -1
  7     23      1     25           4      3     -5      1
  7     23      1     25           4     -3      5      1
  7     23      1     25           4      3     -7     -1
  7     23      1     25           4     -3      7     -1
  7     23      1     25  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      4      5      8           1      1     -1      6
  7      4      5      8           1     -1      1      6
  7      4      5      8           1      1     -3     -6
  7      4      5      8           1     -1      3     -6
  7      4      5      8           1      1      4      1
  7      4      5      8           1     -1     -4      1
  7      4      5      8           1      1     -8     -1
  7      4      5      8           1     -1      8     -1
  7      4      5      8           1      3     -5      2
  7      4      5      8           1     -3      5      2
  7      4      5      8           1      3     -7     -2
  7      4      5      8           1     -3      7     -2
  7      4      5      8           3      1      0      1
  7      4      5      8           3     -1      0      1
  7      4      5      8           3      1     -4     -1
  7      4      5      8           3     -1      4     -1
  7      4      5      8  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      5      1     11           1      4     -5      1
  7      5      1     11           1     -4      5      1
  7      5      1     11           4      1     -1      3
  7      5      1     11           4     -1      1      3
  7      5      1     11           4      1     -3     -3
  7      5      1     11           4     -1      3     -3
  7      5      1     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  7      8      3     12           1      1      0      5
  7      8      3     12           1     -1      0      5
  7      8      3     12           1      1      3      2
  7      8      3     12           1     -1     -3      2
  7      8      3     12           1      1     -4     -5
  7      8      3     12           1     -1      4     -5
  7      8      3     12           1      1     -7     -2
  7      8      3     12           1     -1      7     -2
  7      8      3     12           1      5     -8      1
  7      8      3     12           1     -5      8      1
  7      8      3     12           5      1     -1      2
  7      8      3     12           5     -1      1      2
  7      8      3     12           5      1     -3     -2
  7      8      3     12           5     -1      3     -2
  7      8      3     12  BRUTE FORCE       
  8      1      2     11           1      3     -1      1
  8      1      2     11           1     -3      1      1
  8      1      2     11           3      1     -1      5
  8      1      2     11           3     -1      1      5
  8      1      2     11           3      1     -3     -5
  8      1      2     11           3     -1      3     -5
  8      1      2     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  8     13      2     17           1      1      1      5
  8     13      2     17           1     -1     -1      5
  8     13      2     17           1      1      3      3
  8     13      2     17           1     -1     -3      3
  8     13      2     17           1      1     -5     -5
  8     13      2     17           1     -1      5     -5
  8     13      2     17           1      1     -7     -3
  8     13      2     17           1     -1      7     -3
  8     13      2     17  BRUTE FORCE       
  8     13      6     15           7      1     -1      1
  8     13      6     15           7     -1      1      1
  8     13      6     15           7      1     -3     -1
  8     13      6     15           7     -1      3     -1
  8     13      6     15  BRUTE FORCE       
  8     23      4     25           6      2     -3      1
  8     23      4     25           6     -2      3      1
  8     23      4     25           6      2     -5     -1
  8     23      4     25           6     -2      5     -1
  8     23      4     25  BRUTE FORCE       
  8     29      2     31           3      5     -9      1
  8     29      2     31           3     -5      9      1
  8     29      2     31           5      3     -5      1
  8     29      2     31           5     -3      5      1
  8     29      2     31           5      3     -7     -1
  8     29      2     31           5     -3      7     -1
  8     29      2     31  BRUTE FORCE       
  8     31      0     33           4      4     -7      1
  8     31      0     33           4     -4      7      1
  8     31      0     33           4      4     -9     -1
  8     31      0     33           4     -4      9     -1
  8     31      0     33  BRUTE FORCE       
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -1      1
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      1      1
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -3      3
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      3      3
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -5     -3
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      5     -3
  8      5      4     11           2      2     -7     -1
  8      5      4     11           2     -2      7     -1
  8      5      4     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  8      5      6      9           1      1     -1      7
  8      5      6      9           1     -1      1      7
  8      5      6      9           1      1     -3     -7
  8      5      6      9           1     -1      3     -7
  8      5      6      9           1      1      5      1
  8      5      6      9           1     -1     -5      1
  8      5      6      9           1      1     -9     -1
  8      5      6      9           1     -1      9     -1
  8      5      6      9  BRUTE FORCE       
  8      7      2     13           1      5     -7      1
  8      7      2     13           1     -5      7      1
  8      7      2     13           5      1     -1      3
  8      7      2     13           5     -1      1      3
  8      7      2     13           5      1     -3     -3
  8      7      2     13           5     -1      3     -3
  8      7      2     13  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      0      7      8           1      2     -3      4
  9      0      7      8           1     -2      3      4
  9      0      7      8           1      2     -5     -4
  9      0      7      8           1     -2      5     -4
  9      0      7      8           2      1      2      1
  9      0      7      8           2     -1     -2      1
  9      0      7      8           2      1     -6     -1
  9      0      7      8           2     -1      6     -1
  9      0      7      8  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     12      5     16           1      1      0      7
  9     12      5     16           1     -1      0      7
  9     12      5     16           1      1     -4     -7
  9     12      5     16           1     -1      4     -7
  9     12      5     16           1      1      5      2
  9     12      5     16           1     -1     -5      2
  9     12      5     16           1      1     -9     -2
  9     12      5     16           1     -1      9     -2
  9     12      5     16           7      1     -1      2
  9     12      5     16           7     -1      1      2
  9     12      5     16           7      1     -3     -2
  9     12      5     16           7     -1      3     -2
  9     12      5     16  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     15      7     17           8      1     -1      1
  9     15      7     17           8     -1      1      1
  9     15      7     17           8      1     -3     -1
  9     15      7     17           8     -1      3     -1
  9     15      7     17  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     16      3     20           1      1      1      6
  9     16      3     20           1     -1     -1      6
  9     16      3     20           1      1      4      3
  9     16      3     20           1     -1     -4      3
  9     16      3     20           1      1     -5     -6
  9     16      3     20           1     -1      5     -6
  9     16      3     20           1      1     -8     -3
  9     16      3     20           1     -1      8     -3
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -4      1
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      4      1
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -5      2
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      5      2
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -7     -2
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      7     -2
  9     16      3     20           3      3     -8     -1
  9     16      3     20           3     -3      8     -1
  9     16      3     20  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     18      1     22           1      1      2      5
  9     18      1     22           1     -1     -2      5
  9     18      1     22           1      1      3      4
  9     18      1     22           1     -1     -3      4
  9     18      1     22           1      1     -6     -5
  9     18      1     22           1     -1      6     -5
  9     18      1     22           1      1     -7     -4
  9     18      1     22           1     -1      7     -4
  9     18      1     22           2      5     -8      1
  9     18      1     22           2     -5      8      1
  9     18      1     22           5      2     -3      2
  9     18      1     22           5     -2      3      2
  9     18      1     22           5      2     -5     -2
  9     18      1     22           5     -2      5     -2
  9     18      1     22  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     27      5     29           7      2     -3      1
  9     27      5     29           7     -2      3      1
  9     27      5     29           7      2     -5     -1
  9     27      5     29           7     -2      5     -1
  9     27      5     29  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      3      1     13           1      4     -3      1
  9      3      1     13           1     -4      3      1
  9      3      1     13           4      1     -1      5
  9      3      1     13           4     -1      1      5
  9      3      1     13           4      1     -3     -5
  9      3      1     13           4     -1      3     -5
  9      3      1     13  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      3      5     11           1      2      3      1
  9      3      5     11           1     -2     -3      1
  9      3      5     11           2      1     -1      7
  9      3      5     11           2     -1      1      7
  9      3      5     11           2      1     -3     -7
  9      3      5     11           2     -1      3     -7
  9      3      5     11  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     35      3     37           6      3     -5      1
  9     35      3     37           6     -3      5      1
  9     35      3     37           6      3     -7     -1
  9     35      3     37           6     -3      7     -1
  9     35      3     37  BRUTE FORCE       
  9     39      1     41           4      5     -9      1
  9     39      1     41           4     -5      9      1
  9     39      1     41           5      4     -7      1
  9     39      1     41           5     -4      7      1
  9     39      1     41           5      4     -9     -1
  9     39      1     41           5     -4      9     -1
  9     39      1     41  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      5      3     13           1      2     -1      3
  9      5      3     13           1     -2      1      3
  9      5      3     13           1      2     -7     -3
  9      5      3     13           1     -2      7     -3
  9      5      3     13           2      1      1      3
  9      5      3     13           2     -1     -1      3
  9      5      3     13           2      1     -5     -3
  9      5      3     13           2     -1      5     -3
  9      5      3     13  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      6      1     14           1      2      1      2
  9      6      1     14           1     -2     -1      2
  9      6      1     14           1      2     -9     -2
  9      6      1     14           1     -2      9     -2
  9      6      1     14           1      5     -6      1
  9      6      1     14           1     -5      6      1
  9      6      1     14           2      1      0      5
  9      6      1     14           2     -1      0      5
  9      6      1     14           2      1     -4     -5
  9      6      1     14           2     -1      4     -5
  9      6      1     14           5      1     -1      4
  9      6      1     14           5     -1      1      4
  9      6      1     14           5      1     -3     -4
  9      6      1     14           5     -1      3     -4
  9      6      1     14  BRUTE FORCE       
  9      6      7     10           1      1    -10     -1
  9      6      7     10           1     -1     10     -1
  9      6      7     10           1      1     -1      8
  9      6      7     10           1     -1      1      8
  9      6      7     10           1      1     -3     -8
  9      6      7     10           1     -1      3     -8
  9      6      7     10           1      1      6      1
  9      6      7     10           1     -1     -6      1
  9      6      7     10           1      4     -7      2
  9      6      7     10           1     -4      7      2
  9      6      7     10           1      4     -9     -2
  9      6      7     10           1     -4      9     -2
  9      6      7     10           4      1      0      1
  9      6      7     10           4     -1      0      1
  9      6      7     10           4      1     -4     -1
  9      6      7     10           4     -1      4     -1
  9      6      7     10  BRUTE FORCE       
  a      b      c      d           p      q      r      s
```

==============================================================